# Что такое concurrency и какие есть concurrency классы?

Tags: java

Можете объяснить на пальцах, что это за зверь такой concurrency и как использовать?

Comment: Ответ будет зависеть от того, знакомы ли вы с терминами *поток* (thread) и *многопоточность*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Concurrency это работа с многопоточным кодом.

Обычно под этим понимают:

1. *Управление (создание/запуск/остановка) [потоками](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) виртуальной машины Java (которые "нити", threads).* Код в каждом таком потоке может выполняться параллельно с кодом в других потоках. Таким образом, несколько задач могут быть выполнены как бы одновременно. Тут нужно разобраться с такими понятиями как потоки, пулы потоков, футуры.

   Гуглить и читать:

   - `java.lang.Thread`
   - `java.lang.Runnable`
   - `java.util.concurrent.Callable`
   - `java.util.concurrent.Executor`
   - `java.util.concurrent.Executors`
   - `java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory`
2. *Управление потоком выполнения программы (синхронизация потоков)*. Постоянно возникают ситуации, когда код в одном потоке должен дождаться завершения выполнения задачи в другом потоке. Это достигается применением разнообразных инструментов синхронизации. Важная в данном контексте проблема - [взаимная блокировка потоков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) (deadlock), когда несколько потоков ожидают чего-либо друг от друга.

   Гуглить и читать:

   - `java.lang.Object`: `wait()`, `notify()`, `notifyAll()`
   - `java.util.concurrent.locks.*`
   - `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`
   - `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`
   - `java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier`
   - `java.util.concurrent.Exchanger`
   - `java.util.concurrent.Phaser`
3. *Управление доступом к памяти (к данным) в многопоточной среде*. Тут важно понимание модели памяти Java (Java Memory Model), видимости переменных, атомарности операций и возникновения [состояний гонок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8), потокобезопасных коллекций.

   Гуглить и читать:

   - Модификатор `volatile`
   - `java.lang.ThreadLocal`
   - `java.util.concurrent.atomic.*`
   - `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap`
   - `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`
   - `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet`
   - `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList`

Для глубокого понимания рекомендую прочитать:

- *Java Concurrency in Practice (by Brian Goetz et al.)*
- *[The Java Memory Model](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/)*
- или хотя бы перевод [JMM FAQ](http://habrahabr.ru/company/golovachcourses/blog/221133/)

Answer (score 4):

Concurrency - вкратце возможность исполнения 2ух и более код стейтментов одновременно. Представьте, что код это вода, которая течет по трубе. Необходимо откачать воду из А в Б (аналогия исполнения кода от старта - main до финиша - exit). Учитывая, что нельзя изменить размер трубы, мы просто добавляем еще 1 трубу. Следовательно, в теории мы получаем бОльшую скорость. Кол-во "труб", которые будут использоваться с пользой, зависит от кол-ва ядер у процессора.

Классов достаточно много и их можно найти под java.util.concurrent. Также советую почитать официальную [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html). По поводу использования, все зависит для чего Вы собираетесь это делать. Примитивный пример:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    // код для исполнения в другом потоке
});
thread.start(); // здесь код начинает исполняться в другом потоке
```

Улучшенный пример будет использовать ExecutorService или подобные классы. Советую почитать [тут](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).